# How to add padding and margin to launch screen logo?

Tags: android, nativescript

I tried below to code to add padding and margin for logo in the launch screen in Android but it's not working.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="fill">
    <item android:drawable="@color/ns_theme">
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/sennheiser_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: provide code or any snippet of design please so we could help

Comment: please add the design xml snippet of your launch screen area! where you are using this layerList

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please share the xml code

Answer (score -1):

tr y this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center" />

</item>

</layer-list>
```

it helps you